# SQL UDF split words and return to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, split, user-defined-functions

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(   
    @String NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos)  AS
(        
SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos       
UNION ALL        
SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)          
FROM Split            
WHERE endpos > 0   
)   
SELECT 'Data' = SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
FROM Split
)
GO
```

How do I spilt the words including commas, periods and spaces? At the moment it is just splitting where the commas are.

Comment: If you want to treat all commas, periods and spaces the same, why not use REPLACE() to change them all to commas before passing @String in in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, and [credit to the source](http://raresql.com/2013/01/10/sql-server-split-string-into-rows-based-on-multiple-delimiters/)

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.[UDF_Split_Based_On_Multiple_Delimiters]
(
      @String VARCHAR(MAX),  -- Variable for string
      @delimiter VARCHAR(50) -- Delimiter in the string
)
RETURNS @Table TABLE(        --Return type of the function
Splitcolumn VARCHAR(MAX)
)
BEGIN
        DECLARE @Xml AS XML
        DECLARE @REVISED_STRING VARCHAR(MAX)

        ;WITH N1 (n) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
        N2 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N1 AS X, N1 AS Y),
        N3 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM N2 AS X, N2 AS Y),
        N4 (n) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY X.n)
        FROM N3 AS X, N3 AS Y)

        SELECT @REVISED_STRING=STUFF((SELECT '' + (Case When
                PATINDEX('%[' + @delimiter + ']%',SUBSTRING(@String,Nums.n,1)) >0
                Then ',' else LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@String,Nums.n,1))) end)
        FROM N4 Nums WHERE Nums.n<=LEN(@String)  FOR XML PATH('')),1,0,'')

        SET @Xml = cast(('<a>'+replace(@REVISED_STRING,
                ',','</a><a>')+'</a>') AS XML)

        INSERT INTO @Table SELECT A.value('.', 'varchar(max)')
                as [Column] FROM @Xml.nodes('a') AS FN(a)
RETURN
END
GO
```