# Joining Tables on fields with matching words within a sentence

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join

I have basic knowledge of SQL and joining tables, however I have now come across something fairly past my level of knowledge. I want to join two tables where the fields the join will occur may have various words, I wish to compare the two fields and find a match of a specific word in both.

---

```
**TblBuildData** 

BuildNo | Defect

123456 | REAR LEFT WHEEL SPOKE SCRATCH

123456 | REAR LEFT TYRE PUNCTURE
```

---

```
**TblPostBuildData**

BuildNo | Defect

123456 | CRACKED WHEEL SPOKE

123456 | MISSING TYRE VALVE
```

---

The query would match TblBuildData's REAR LEFT WHEEL SPOKE SCRATCH to TblPostBuildData's CRACKED WHEEL SPOKE because they both had the word wheel. I don't want to specify the keyword of wheel I wish for the query to match likenesses.

Is this possible? Thanks for looking.

Comment: This isn't readily supported in SQL.  If you try to do it, then the performance will be pretty bad.  Also, why don't they match on the word "SPOKE"?

Comment: Yeah they could match on the word Spoke too, slight oversight in my example. It would also match on Tyre too. Although not readily supported, is it possible with small tables?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I think it's SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a function that takes a row and returns a table that contains all individual words, you could use a combination of [EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) (msdn.microsoft.com) and [INTERSECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) (msdn.microsoft.com) to see if any words match.

You can find this kind of function if you search on the internets (eg [SQL UDF split words and return to table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635499/sql-udf-split-words-and-return-to-table)).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a split function to break the column down into multiple rows.  What I pasted below should work to create a function on your database to do so called Split.  This will take a row as the first parameter, a delimiter to split by for the second (in this case we will use a space), and will return a table with one column called items.

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String varchar(MAX), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(MAX))       
as       
begin      
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)       

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return 
end;
```

Then you could make up 2 CTE that each use outer apply to that function.  The function returns a table containing one column with one row for each word in the specific column.  It will be returned as items and joined to each row of your tables for each word in items for that row.  Then simply join those 2 CTE together on those words found in the items columns.

```
with tablea as (
    SELECT a.BuildNo, a.Defect, items 
    from TblBuildData a
    outer apply [dbo].[Split](a.Defect, ' ')), 
tableb as (
    SELECT b.BuildNo, b.Defect, items 
    from TblPostBuildData b 
    outer apply [dbo].[Split](b.Defect, ' '))
select t1.BuildNo as BuildNo1, t1.Defect as Defect1, t1.items as Items1, 
       t2.BuildNo as BuildNo2, t2.Defect as Defect2, t2.items as Items2
from tablea t1 
inner join tableb t2 on t1.items=t2.items
```

This would then return 3 rows from your example above.  One joined on wheel, One joined on spoke, and one on tyre.

I know this goes a bit beyond basic SQL but this is how I would do it.  I would suggest looking into CTE, OUTER APPLY, and FUNCTION.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select Table1.*, Table2.z
From Table1
Inner join Table2
On Table1.Name like Concat('%',Table2.Name,'%')
```